# compare each cell in one dataframe to all values within a column in a second data frame and count the number of times the first df cell recedes in r

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, join, rowsum

Would like to count the number of times a value in the whole column of DF2(DF2$B) recedes below each cell in DF1$A.

Example:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(Q=c("fun","fun"),
                  A=c(200,700))
DF2 <- data.frame(Z=as.Date(c("2023-10-01","2023-10-02","2023-10-03","2023-10-04")),
                  B=c(600,500,100,800))
```

Desired Output:

```
DF1$Counter <- c(1,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [`findInterval`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/findInterval). Note that you have to `sort` the `DF2$B` column first

```
DF1$Counter <- findInterval(DF1$A, sort(DF2$B))
DF1
    Q   A Counter
1 fun 200       1
2 fun 700       3
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative with sapply would be...

```
DF1$Counter <- sapply(DF1$A, function(x, y) {sum(y < x)}, y = DF2$B)
```